# Android : Checking connectivity to Ip address

Tags: android, ip, connectivity

I got the following code from the intenet

```
      public boolean isConnectedToServer(String url, int timeout) {
    try {
        URL myUrl = new URL(url);
        URLConnection connection = myUrl.openConnection();
        connection.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
        connection.connect();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Handle your exceptions
        return false;
    }
}
```

whenever i am calling this method :

```
    System.out.println(isConnectedToServer("192.168.1.65",5));
```

the output is still `false` and i can easily access my web service file so there is connectivity to this ip but i can't check if the ip is reachable, any thoughts ?

PS: using a local IP address just to connect to my XAMPP server

the Error:

```
    java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: 192.168.1.65
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with your ip. Try using http://ip... An URL is not an URI.

Reference: [Protocol not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12934621/java-net-malformedurlexception-protocol-not-found-read-to-html-file)

See this code and look if it works:

[Other example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905358/how-to-ping-external-ip-from-java-android)

Then you will have another problem. It is the thread you are working in. You are executing this code on the main thread, which generates an exception.

Your second problem: [Network on main thread exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Use an Async task to resolve this.

reference: [Asynctask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: Ah okay, thats great , 1 more question please , in my case what should i put inside the < > in the `Async` method ?

Comment: how do you mean ? Declaring an Asynctask or ?